# "starched collar on loan" meaning

Tags: idiom-meaning

> Yet the new king does not have to be a statesman to succeed. And that is the second reason Britain’s constitutional monarchy has thrived. His powers will be as circumscribed as a starched collar on loan from the nation. The more assertively he exercises them, the less potent they will be.

[(The Economist)](https://www.economist.com/leaders/2022/09/15/why-the-monarchy-matters)

*His powers will be as circumscribed as a starched collar on loan from the nation.*  I think there's a idiom in this line, but i can't identify it. Please clarify for me.

Comment: A stiffy collar, something that limits your movements. His powers are  limited to some extent.

Comment: What about the "on loan" part?

Comment: The starched collar is “loaned” to the  king by the nation.

Comment: Can you give me more information here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider this more of a metaphor than an idiom - a starched collar is restrictive and  uncomfortable though it might make you *look* more presentable, and being "borrowed" means it can be taken away easily.

Answer (score 2):

starched  is used figuratively:

OED

> **starch (v.) 3.a.** transitive. **To make (oneself, a person, the face or features, etc.) formal, severe, or haughty; to make
> (discourse, speech, etc.) formal or excessively serious.**
>
> 2009   S. Walker Power of Tolkien's Prose v. 143   *The dwarvish
> dialect is formal and formulaic, ‘a fair jaw-cracker’ starched with
> ceremonial phrase.*

From which

> **Starched: 2.** figurative. **Stiff, formal; prim;** = starchy adj.
>
> **a.   Of a person, a person's countenance, behaviour, etc.**
>
> 1837   C. Dickens Pickwick Papers xxvii. 276   *His looks were
> starched, but his white neckerchief was not.*
>
> 2006   Psychologies (U.K. ed.) July 45/4   *She has set her heart on a handsome but heavily starched academic..who is poised to be unhappily married to a frumpy killjoy.*

I have heard "he is a starched collar" (where "collar" is synecdoche - compare "a **suit** from head office")) in the sense of a stiff/formal/prim person but can find no examples as "starched collar" is so common in its literary meaning.